# How can we integrate angular 2 application with Angular JS app?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Actually I designed one app in Angular 2. I want to integrate that angular 2 app with Angular JS app.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose 4 things should be interoperate between Angular 1 and Angular 2:

- Dependency injection
- Component nesting
- Transclusion
- Change detection

and to deal with these four requirements you need ng-upgrade

[Check this Angular 1 and Angular 2 integration: the path to seamless upgrade](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2015/08/angular-1-and-angular-2-coexistence.html)

you can see this [for more details on how NgUpgrade works](https://blog.nrwl.io/ngupgrade-in-depth-436a52298a00)

**Angular 1 to Angular 2 Upgrade Strategy**

Angular 1 and Angular 2 have different syntax and semantics. Attempting to convert the whole app wholesale is not feasible for most production applications how ever you can see this on how to perform this

what should be your strategy for integration/upgrade [see this guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xvBZoFuNq9hsgRhPPZOJC-Z48AHEbIBPlOCBTSD8m0Y/edit#heading=h.dyvip3fq0v97)